# MySqli Object properties are null

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

I am stumbling into the following issue.. I am trying to retrieve some information from my DB using Ajax, however, my query is failing for some reason, when trying to debug it by analyzing the information within the mysqli_object, all the properties are null:

I printed the contents of the object of the console:

```
affected_rows:null
client_info:null
client_version:null
connect_errno:null
connect_error:null
errno:null
error:null
error_list:null
field_count:null
host_info:null
info:null
insert_id:null
protocol_version:null
server_info:null
server_version:null
sqlstate:null
stat:null
thread_id:null
warning_count:null
```

Why can this happen?

Here's my Ajax call:

```
$('#npClientName').keyup(function(){
  var txt = $(this).val();
  if (txt == "") {
    $('#npClientList').fadeOut();
    return false;
  }

  $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/fitcoControl/Resources/PHP/Clientes/fetchPopupClientList.php',
    data:{txt: txt},
    success: function(result){
      rsp = JSON.parse(result);
      console.log(rsp);

      if (rsp.code != "1") {
        $('#npClientList').html("<p>Hubo un error al cargar la lista de clientes...</p>");
        console.warn("Error en el query: " + rsp.response);
      } else {
        $('#npClientList').html(rsp.response);
      }
      $('#npClientList').fadeIn();
      clientSelector();
    },
    error: function(exception){
      console.error(exception);
    }
  });
});
```

And here's my PHP code:

```
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$data = array(
  'code'=>"",
  'response'=>""
);

$txt = "'%" . $_POST['txt'] . "%'";

require $root . "/fitcoControl/Resources/PHP/DataBases/Conexion.php";
$query = "SELECT * FROM ct_cliente";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
//$stmt->bind_param('s', $txt);
$stmt->execute();

$resultados = $stmt->get_result();
$num_rows = $stmt->num_rows;

if (false) {
  $data['code'] = 2;
  //$data['response'] = $num_rows;
} else {
  $data['code'] = 1;
  $data['system'] = $conn;
  while ($a = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultados)) {
    $idCliente = $a['pk_cliente'];
    $nc = $a['nombreCliente'];
    $data['response'] .= "<p client-id='$idCliente'>$nc</p>";
  }
}



$json = json_encode($data);

echo $json;
```

Ideas?

Comment: Seems like the connection might have failed. Do you check for errors?

Comment: when you used this code did you get json data in console? or any error?

Comment: No error at all, I modified the query, and it's returning the dataset properly, but the mysqli_object is still returning NULL values. I don't get what's going on here.

Comment: I am unsure how php understands this line: `if (false) {` ... Shouldn't be `if (!$resultados) {` instead ?

Comment: I had to force the script to go to the 'if false' scenario, since I can't access mysqli properties, $resultados returns null.